# C# NHibernate Connected but not returning data and no error

Tags: nhibernate, data-retrieval

I have a C# Windows App running on my local box that is connected to an intranet.  I am using nHibernate as the ORM.  We use the same nHibernate ORM settings on our web site.  The web site performs all the CRUD operations appropriately using the nHibernate ORM.  However, my Windows app is not retrieving any data.  The Session is initialized, the Connection is connected and the DB has data.  There are no errors when calling .FindFirst() or .FindAllProposals(), just no data returned.  Here's a snapshot of the repository object and it's connection status:

[image]

Here's a code snippet from the repository class:

```
public class ProposalRepository : NHRepository<Proposal>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Queries the database for all Proposals.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of Proposals sorted newest first.</returns>
    public IList<Proposal> FindAllProposals()
    {
        return FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<Proposal>(),
                            new Order("CreateDate", false)).ToList<Proposal>();
    }
}
```

It appears connected, active and open.  Any ideas why no data is being returned?

Comment: you haven't posted the code for `FindAll` method...

Comment: @Johnny.....FindAll is a default method in the base class  Rhino.Commons.RepositoryImplBase<T> which our NHRepository inherits from

Answer (score 2):

You must change the build action of the hbm.xml file.
[image]